# SaveChangesAsync not updating navigation property

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, savechanges

I have users `public virtual ICollection<File> Files` navigation property. And im trying to remove file

```
var user = await _unitOfWork.UserRepository
                .GetUserByName(User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.GivenName));
var image = user.Files.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == imageId);

user.Image = null;
user.Files.Remove(image);

if (await _unitOfWork.Complete())
{
    return Ok();
}
```

It's removing it from files but not updating in database. I tried this:
`await _unitOfWork.UserRepository.UpdateUser(user);` and it didn't work

UpdateUser(User user):

```
_context.Users.Attach(user);
_context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

UnitOfWork:

```
public async Task<bool> Complete()
{
    return await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;
}
```

It works fine with adding `user.Files.Add(image)` but i dont understand whats problem with removing

Comment: Where are you actually deleting the `image`?

Comment: @mxmissile `user.Files.Remove(image);` it's deleting image from navigation property `public virtual ICollection<File> Files` and after savechanges it should remove it from database too

Comment: Pls post User and File classes

Comment: @Serge in file `public int UserId { get; set; } public virtual User User { get; set; }
}` and in user class its just `public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }`

Comment: Could you share your `user` class in the question as well?

Comment: The method in which the call is executed has `async Task` or `async Task<IActionResult>` as return type?

Comment: @Carlos `async Task<ActionResult>`

Comment: Can you show the code of the GetUserByName() method?

Comment: @Carlos `public async Task<User> GetUserByName(string username)
    {
        return await _context.Users
            .Where(u => u.UserName == username)
            .ProjectTo<User>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync() ?? throw new NotFoundException(username);
    }`

Comment: and does it work when you use `SaveChanges` instead of `SaveChangesAsync`? Just so we can be sure that it is indeed a problem with asynchronicity

Comment: Have you tried to include Files? e.g. `_context.Users.Include(u => u.Files).Where(...)`

Comment: @Carlos i changed to SaveChanges and it worked at first but then i had same issue

Comment: Okay, that was just for testing purposes so we can be sure that the async save is the problem. That being said, I do have problems with saveChangesAsync every now and then and I just use saveChanges...